# c++ Qt Expression : _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) error

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, memory-leaks

I am trying to figure out why I get this error. I have seen many questions/answers about the same, but I just don't see any of the reasons that could be causing me this error on my code.

From the research I have been doing, the possible reasons for this error are:

1 - I am deleting objects more than once

2 - shadow copying

3 - I am creating and deleting Objects that are loaded from an external dll

4 - I am creating objects without storing the pointer

Here is my code:

**TreeView.h**

```
 #pragma once
 #include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
 #include <QtWidgets/QTreeView>
 #include <QtWidgets/QTreeWidgetItem>
 #include <QtWidgets\qfilesystemmodel.h>
 #include <QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h>
 #include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
 #include <QtWidgets/QDirModel>
 #include <QtCore/QDebug>
 #include <QtCore\qtimer.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <QtCore\qmap.h>
 #include <QtWidgets/QFileDialog>
 #include <QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h>

using namespace std;

class Tree: public QTreeView {  
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    QFileSystemModel *model;
    QPushButton *button;

    Tree(QWidget *parent = 0):QTreeView(parent){
        this->resize(200,600);
        //create the tree  
        string directory = "C:\\Users\\Alloisio\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\TreeView\\TreeWidget\\Indicators\\Factores";
        model = new QFileSystemModel(this);
        model->setRootPath( directory.c_str());
        this->setModel(model);
        this->setRootIndex(model->setRootPath(directory.c_str()));

        this->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection); //allow multi select with Ctrl 

        //button
        button = new QPushButton(this);
        button->setText("Display Selected");
        button->move(30,600);

        QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT (muitiselect()));
    }

    public slots:
        void muitiselect(){
            this->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
        }
};
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include "TreeView.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     Tree *tree = new Tree;
     tree->show();
     app.exec();
}
```

Here is what I found out. The error is coming right after executing the function:

```
void muitiselect(){
    this->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
}
```

Would really appreciated any sort of help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be doing everything right by dynamically allocating things and allowing Qt to clean them up; however, there is one example you are not doing that, which is:

```
QWidget widget;
QHBoxLayout horizontalLayout(&widget);
```

Here, when the `horizontalLayout` is destroyed it destroys the `widget`, which will also try to destroy itself when its scope finishes. Try:

```
QWidget* widget = new QWidget();
QHBoxLayout horizontalLayout(widget);
```

See [`QLayout::addWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#addWidget) which internally uses [`QLayout::addItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#addItem)

> Note: The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it.

Comment: Thank you for having a look on the problem. I have checked and the error is not coming from there. I have actually figure out where the error is coming from and I am editing the question right now.Please have a look